# How to link Table of content itself in bookmark

Tags: table-of-contents, links

The problem I facing is this.
[image]

When I click on "Table of Contents" bookmark it takes me to "Acknowledgement" section instead. When I click "Acknowledgement" it takes me to "Acknowledgement" section which is correct but why can it take me to "Table of Content" section when I click the bookmark "Table of Content"?
My code is this

```
\documentclass[sfdefaults=false,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{report}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\graphicspath{{./sec/image/}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\date{\today}
%\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}% Don't print section number in section titles.
\sectionfont{\centering}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\input{sec/titlepage}

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman} % roman page numbers

\input{sec/second_page} % The page next to Title Page
\input{sec/approval_sheet} 
\input{sec/declaration} 
\input{sec/acknowledgment}

\newpage
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\centering TABLE OF CONTENTS}% This will change heading text 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\tableofcontents
% List of figures - if any

\newpage
\listoffigures 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF FIGURES}

% List of tables- if any

\newpage
\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{LIST OF TABLES}

% List of Abbreviation- if any
\input{sec/abbreviations}
%Abstract
\input{sec/abstract}

%Begining of Main Body
\newpage
\input{sec/introduction}
\input{sec/literature_review}
\input{sec/methodology}
% \input{sec/result}
%\input{sec/conclusion}
\input{sec/references}
% \input{sec/appendix} %optional
\end{document}
```

Comment: `addcontentsline` should be after `phantomsection`

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much @Mane32

Comment: How do I mark your answer as a correct answer @Mane32?

Comment: I just added it as an answer. You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order of the commands you are using. Instead of using first `\addcontentsline` and then `\phantomsection`, you need to first create the `phantomsection` and then use `addcontentsline` so the hyperlink anchors to the last `phantomsection` created.

You need to do this also with your others lists of things you are adding to your bookmarks.